# Specific href after joomla's modal window close

Tags: joomla, mootools, joomla1.5

I have a **Joomla 1.5.26** site here and I am trying to make **modal window** take specific **href** on **close**. Looking into **modal.js** file, I found this part of code...
`this.btnClose = new Element('a', {id:'sbox-btn-close', href:'#', title:'Close'});` I am changing the `href:'#'` to `href:'index.php'` for example, but nothing happens! When I close modal window doesn't get **index.php**. Any idea? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modal library used in Joomla is [SqueezeBox](http://digitarald.de/project/squeezebox/)

I advice against modifying Joomla core libraries.
You should use Squeezebox API instead: add a listener to close event:

```
SqueezeBox.addEvent('onClose', function() {
    window.location = 'index.php';
});
```

*Modal window might be by other means like by outside out it.*

the element `<a id="sbox-btn-close" href="#" />` is just an UI element that observes clicks but it's native functionality is suppressed (doesn't work like link).

If you are asking yourself, why it's `<a href="#" />` and not `<span />`, the trick is to show a pointer cursor when you point mouse over it - without using CSS.

Comment: You can do lot's of interesting stuff with SqueezeBox.

Comment: Do you have something like tutorial, guide or anything?

Comment: For starting links to: 
[SqueezeBox manual](http://digitarald.de/project/squeezebox/),  
[MooTools Class: Events](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Class/Class.Extras#Events),   
When you add in your Joomla template `<?php JHTML::_('behavior.modal', 'a.modal'); ?>`, all links with class `modal` will open in SqueezeBox. You may define modal size, load Ajax and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much my friend! Please take a look what I made [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430218/article-open-in-modal-window-after-a-user-click-on-facebook-share-link-and-come) and tell me your opinion. Look straight on the acceptable answer. If you have any correction or something please let me know!!!

Thank you for your time!

Comment: @piotr_cs: One more thing my friend. How can I add the option, don't close if someone click outside modal? Thank you for your time!